# How to call Objective C function (similar to delegate ) from Python

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, callback, pyobjc

I am working an example,where I have to communicate between `Python` and `Objective C` using `Bonjour` protocol.I was able to communicate between a Mac and iOS Program using `Bonjour`.
For Python I installed `pybonjour` and I am able to register services using the examples.
After this I want to send some messages to `iOS` program which requires exchange of `streams`.

In `iOS` Program created a socket and a `callback function` was in place and this 
 `callback function` is in C. What changes are required to invoke `callback function` (which is in `iOS`) from `Python`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Does the Python code run on iOS as well? If it doesn't, you just need to write data to the socket connection and then the socket callback is called when that data is received on iOS.